# How to select node where descendant node has attribute

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am parsing an html email.  I need to get the href property from the following html:

```
 <a href="https://sample.com/us/en/suv-rental/united-states/orlando-fl/jeep/grand-cherokee/12345" target="_blank">
     <img class="m_3371787045960899181vehicle-image" width="360" height="216" src="https://images.sample.com/media/vehicle/images/12345.620x372.jpg" alt="Jeep Grand Cherokee" title="Jeep Grand Cherokee">
 </a>
```

The only way to select it is to find the `a` which has an image, which has a src which includes 'https://images.sample.com'

What I need is: `https://sample.com/us/en/suv-rental/united-states/orlando-fl/jeep/grand-cherokee/12345`

I am struggling to get this to work.  This is what I have so far:

```
 HtmlNode vehicleNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a").Where(x => x.DescendantNodes.Attributes["src"].Value.Contains("images.sample.com")).First();
```

But this does not compile, as you cannot use `x.DescendantNodes...`  but I cannot find the correct way to do this.

So how to select using a decendant node property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, in terms of XPath you can use `//a[img/@src[starts-with(., 'https://images.sample.com')]]`.